# signal interactive in unix

Tags: c, unix, signals

I get the following code which confuse me so mush

```
static jmp_buf env_alrm;
static void sig_alrm1(int signo){
    longjmp(env_alrm,1);
}

unsigned int sleep2(unsigned int nsecs){
    if(signal(SIGALRM ,sig_alrm) == SIG_ERR)
        return(nsecs);
    if(setjmp(env_alrm) == 0){
        alarm(nsecs);
        pause();
    }
    return(alarm(0));
}
static void sig_int(int);
int main(void){
    unsigned  int unslept;
    if(signal(SIGINT,sig_int) == SIG_ERR)
        err_sys("signal (sigint) error");
    unslept = sleep2(5);
    printf("sleep2 return ed :%u\n" ,unslept);
    exit(0);
}
static void sig_int(int signo){
    int i,j;
    volatile int k;
    printf("\nsig_int staring\n");
    for(i = 0;i<30000;i++)
        for(j = 0;j<4000;j++)
            k += i *j;
    printf("sig_int finished");
}
```

while the sleep function is working ,if i press ctrl+c.
what is really happening?does it gonna ignore SIGALRM and run sig_int then exit?

Answer (score 3):

First there are two signal handlers setup for `SIGINT` and `SIGALRM` in `main` and `sleep2` respectively. Then an alarm is setup which would deliver `SIGALRM` in `nsecs` (which is 5) and `pause` is called which waits for *any* signal.

If you send SIGINT (<kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>) while in `sleep2` function, then its signal handler `sig_int` is called and once it returns, it causes `pause` to return. At last, `return(alarm(0));` returns the number of seconds left before the previously setup alarm if it were to be delivered.

So if you send `SIGINT` within 5 seconds (i.e. before SIGALRM is sent by `alarm(nsecs)` call) then `sleep2` will return the `5-x` seconds (`x` is roughly the the number of seconds elapsed since the start of the program).

It's basically down to who wakes up `pause` first: `SIGINT` sent by you or the `SIGALRM` sent by `alarm(nsecs)` call. And the output of `unslept` will be based on that.

---

I see that this is an example from the book [APUE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321637739). It explains why setjmp/longjmp is used here.

The idea of setjmp/longjmp combination is used to ensure the program is not stuck in `pause` in case the `SIGALRM` is delivered *before* `pause` has been called. If setjmp/longjmp were not there and  a signal `SIGALRM` is processed before `pause()` kicks in, then `pause()` will wait forever for a signal as it's unaware of the previous `SIGALRM` delivered.

The book (Chapter 10 Signals) goes on to explain why even this is not perfect as longjmp (in SIGALRM handler) might abort other signal handlers.

Comment: The last paragraph is of paramount importance to understand what happens with the code. The goal with the handler for `SIGINT` is that it runs for more than 5 seconds (hence the nested loops), and it shows how this is not a good implementation of `sleep()` because it will cancel execution of `sig_int()` when `SIGALRM` is triggered. The goal of the example is to show that even though `longjmp` / `setjmp` solve the race condition with `pause()`, they introduce the problem of potentially canceling other handlers in the midst of execution.